# Diagonal line is borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Define the diagonal line $D:=${$(x,y):x=y$}.

I want to show that D is measurable. To be more specific, $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B} $ measurable.

I did not really know how to start, so the first thing I did was to write down all relevant definitions.

Definition: (measurrable)
Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$ algebra on X. We call a set $A$ measurable, if $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Definition: (borel)
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the collection of open subsets of $X$, we call $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ the borel sigma algebra on $X$.

Lemma:
In the case of $X=\mathbb{R}$, the Borel sigma algebra is generated by
$C_1=${$[a,b]: a,b \in \mathbb{R}$}.
The \sigma-algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is denoted by $\mathcal{B}_n$.

Lemma:
Let $\mathcal{B}_m$ be the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathcal{B}_n$ the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathcal{B}_m \otimes \mathcal{B}_n=\mathcal{B}_{m+n}$.

Now, since $[0,1]$ is $\in C_1$, thus [0,1] \in $\mathcal{B}_1$.
And the lemma above ensures that $\mathcal{B}_1 \otimes \mathcal{B}_1=\mathcal{B}_2$, hence set $[0,1]^2 \in \mathcal{B}_2$.

Is this correct?
I know that the stated lemma holds for $X=\mathbb{R}$, but does it still work for $X=[0,1]$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{B}_m \otimes \mathcal{B}_n$?

Comment: @JonathanZ the product measure

Comment: @Peter Think you mean the product $\sigma$-algebra, there's no measure here. Also, it seems the only question you ask here is if the $\mathcal B\otimes \mathcal B$ result holds for $[0,1]$ as well as $\mathbb R$ (it does) whereas you got answers to the headline question you never asked about the diagonal that assume this. It holds for the same reason it holds for $\mathbb R$: products of open intervals generate the Borel algebra on $[0,1]^2,$ since any open set is a countable union of them (or whatever proof you have for $\mathbb R$ should be easily adaptable).

Answer (score 2):

Since the product algebra is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$, all closed sets are measurable. Since the diagonal is closed, we're done.